# Using urllib to send get request

Tags: python

I have this python code.

```
from urllib import request
req =  request.Request(url, data={})
req.add_header('Referer', 'my_original_header')
res = request.urlopen(req)
```

However it send the post request to this url.

SO I try this instead

```
res=request.get(url, headers={"Referer":"my_original_header"})
```

However it shows there is no `get` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to use the method .get try using a module called requestS.

```
import requests
res=requests.get('https://3dthings.online', headers{"Referer":"my_original_header"})
res.content
```